# C# MYSQL проблема с заполнением combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Есть такой код:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace menu_mysql
{
  public partial class menu1 : Form
  {           
    public menu1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='testmenu';username=root;password=");

//код...

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM testmenu.foods";
            MySqlCommand commad = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connect);


            MySqlDataReader read1;
            try
                {
                connect.Open();
                read1 = commad.ExecuteReader();

                while (read1.Read())
                {
                    string fdtype = read1.GetString("food");
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(fdtype);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

`СomboBox1` не отображает данные из таблицы, как это исправить?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67651/discussion-on-question-by-beginneroot-c-mysql----combobox).

Answer (score 1):

Причиной того, что не отображались данные в `comboBox1` является то, что код был размещён внутри `combobox1` :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM testmenu.foods";
        MySqlCommand commad = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connect);


        MySqlDataReader read1;
        try
            {
            connect.Open();
            read1 = commad.ExecuteReader();

            while (read1.Read())
            {
                string fdtype = read1.GetString("food");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(fdtype);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

а надо было его поместить внутрь самой формы:

```
 private void menu1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM testmenu.foods";
            connect.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connect);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString("food"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

желаю что бы другие не ошибались как я, спасибо!